# Chrome driver throwing script results error on FindElement calls

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

After updating yesterday to Chrome browser version 76.0.3809.87 and updating my Chrome drivers to version 76.0.3809.68 we are experiencing strange exceptions on a set of websites when using the `FindElements`, `FindElementByXPath`, and `FindElement` methods. This issue was not happening pre-update. The exception thrown is:

> unknown error: script returns unexpected result.

Currently my project automates somewhere around 500-600 websites, and we are only experiencing this issue (so far) on 3 sites:

- https://billing.clarksvillegw.com/iwr/user/login.seam
- https://mwsonline.nashville.gov/iwr/user/login.seam
- https://webconnect.greensboro-nc.gov/iwr/user/login.seam

Each of these sites are built by the same company so the code is comparable. When using the `FindElementById` method, this exception is not thrown. It doesn't seem to matter what XPath you give the method either, the exception is thrown each time. I have tried creating a new project with a fresh selenium install and the results are the same.

I'm sure this has something to do with the Chrome driver update, and to do with the actual implementation of `FindElements` which I have searched for but am unable to find. My guess is that it is using some javascript in the backend which is not playing nice with the website.

I have not attempted to reproduce this issue with another driver. Given some of our project constraints, we are unable to use anything but Chrome driver at the moment.

Searching for this issue yields no results, as this is a fresh issue. Searching for the exception message just yields things about using `ExecuteScript` incorrectly, which is (I assume) irrelevant to my question.

Does anyone know what would cause this on the website? Or if there is a known workaround? Just want to make sure that I am not doing anything specific that is causing this issue before I submit a help ticket for this issue.

```
try
{
    var driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://billing.clarksvillegw.com/iwr/user/login.seam");
    var success = driver.FindElementsById("login:usernamedec:username").Any();
    var failure = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id='login:usernamedec:username']").Any();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

When using the code above, `success` is computed correctly, but when trying to compute `failure` the code throws the exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have exactly the same error after upgrading Chrome browser and ChromeDriver to 76.0.3809.87 on our test automation server, running Selenium-Webdriver and Appium on ruby.

Have narrowed down the cause of the problem and ended up getting errors returned from this method below - when calling table object with row/column reference, ie.

```
`execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: 'center'});", self.sales_table_element[ref][@ref_col])`
```

[Cheezy page-object](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/master/lib/page-object/elements/table.rb)

```
`def row_items
    meth = strategy == :descendants ? :trs : :rows
    @row_items ||= element.send(meth).map do |obj|
      ::PageObject::Elements::TableRow.new(obj)
    end
 end`
```

**Workaround:** Downgrade Chrome-Driver to [75.0.3770.140](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=75.0.3770.140/) fixes the problem for me

This is an interim solution from now. Hope this issue get permanently fixed soon!

**UPDATE:** Upgrade both ChromeDriver and Chrome brower to 77.0.3865.40 fixes the issue. - See also, https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.40/notes.txt

Comment: Thanks for this, we're seeing an error with 76 as well and are trying this too: https://github.com/publiclab/plots2/pull/6094

Comment: Actually, I haven't been able to find a link to a binary file for Chrome 75, to match with this. Do you know where we can find one?

Comment: Hi jywarren, my solution above was to downgrade ChromeDriver only - to 75.0.3770.140. Chrome browser was still running on 76.0.3809.87

Answer (score 1):

This issue is described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromedriver-users/c4fO7ArJ5TI) and reproduced when page under test use prototypejs v1.6.1

Corresponding bug [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3084) (closed now) and should be released to new builds of chromedrivers v76, v77 next week (after Aug 26, 2019)  FYI: current version of chromedrivers are: 76.0.3809.68 and 77.0.3865.10

Using previous driver version should work, with chromedriver v75 you should have warnings only that "current versionwas not tested". But for v74 you'll need to launch driver with [`--disable-build-check`](https://github.com/bayandin/chromedriver/blob/c16855442e341d01bc0067e1aeefea212e2d152f/chrome_launcher.cc#L258)

Comment: Have upgraded ChromeDriver to 77.0.3865.40 and it definitely fixes the issue - running matching version on Chrome browser. See here - https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.40/notes.txt

Answer (score -1):

Using the prior chromedriver (75.0.3770.140) did not work for me.  Anyone have another solution yet?